# Keras simple neural network for NOT logic generating wrong output

Tags: python-2.7, keras

I am new to deep learning and I am trying to implement `NOT` logic in `keras`. But the results are not correct. Below is the code.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

inputs = Input(shape=(1,))
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(input=inputs, output=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

X = np.array([[0.], [1.]], dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array([[1.], [0.]], dtype=np.float32)
print "learning....."
model.fit(X, y, nb_epoch=100)
print model.predict(X)
```

**Output:**
On every epoch the output is same:

```
Epoch 100/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5000
```

and the predictions are:

```
[[ 1.]
 [ 1.]]
```

I am not sure, what is wrong with this network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of the loss looks wrong. Softmax is typically used for multi-class predictions and you already setup the output to be consisting of 2 values using `Dense(2)`. Therefore make your target a multi-class target of `dim=2`.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

inputs = Input(shape=(1,))
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(input=inputs, output=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

X = np.array([[0.], [1.]], dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array([[1., 0], [0., 1]], dtype=np.float32)
print "learning....."
model.fit(X, y, nb_epoch=100)
print model.predict(X)
```

Output

```
Epoch 100/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 1.5137e-07 - acc: 1.0000
[[  9.99880254e-01   1.19736877e-04]
 [  5.35955711e-04   9.99464035e-01]]
```

**Edit:** One can argue if the above setup of final-layer activation and loss-function is a good one for binary-classification (probably not). [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40556580/extremely-basic-neural-network-not-learning)

Alternative using sigmoid and only one target:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

inputs = Input(shape=(1,))
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(input=inputs, output=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

X = np.array([[0.], [1.]], dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array([1., 0.], dtype=np.float32)
print "learning....."
model.fit(X, y, nb_epoch=100)
print model.predict(X)
```

Output

```
Epoch 100/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 9.9477e-07 - acc: 1.0000
[[ 0.99945992]
 [ 0.00129277]]
```

Comment: @MrPyCharm You're welcome. I just added some edit including a link which you should also read. It's just a small warning about the setup in the first case (softmax with mse).